# When creating iOS and Android apps in Cordova from web-app, does "/" = domain url?

Tags: cordova, web-applications, absolute-path

When running the following in a website or web-app, it successfully displays an image

```
<img class="ad63" src="/books/BILLY/userAd.jpg?1625022035758" alt="ad" width="280">
```

Will the same be true once the iOS and Android versions are built from the same codebase in Cordova, or will an absolute path be required like so?

```
<img class="ad63" src="https://www.example.com/books/BILLY/userAd.jpg?1625022035758" alt="ad" width="280">
```

I ask as my live web-app has a var in js that I use when dynamically building site resource paths. So my production site is:

```
wwwURL = "https://www.example.com/"
```

My test domain test.example.com is

```
wwwURL = "https://test.example.com/"
```

and localhost for local development in WAMP is...

```
wwwURL = "/"
```

This works ok, but then I realised I probably just need to make my site resource links start with "/" - then they should load no matter what domain or machine I'm running it on, and I don't need the wwwURL var at all. This works on my site and locally, but will it work once a developer compiles the web-app for iOS and Android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.
For instance, links in CSS files (like background images) might not work when targeting `www root` with `/` and you will most likely have to resort to using relative paths (iOS vs Android vs Browser).
When it comes to the local URL in terms of JavaScript, yes, `/` will be the root of the `www` folder.